# How to use click function with $(this) on children elements with the same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, this

I want to create dropdown with country->region->city selection.
The first ul opens from click on that span and the others set to show on hover (code at the bottom).

```
<input type="text" id="srch-area" alt="" class="c-textfield suggestionsInput " name="locationStr" maxlength="" size="" tabindex="3" title="" value="Deutschland" defaultvalue="" highlight="y" strict="y" autocomplete="off">
<span class="c-icon-arrow-green-down-left c-icon" id="loc-slctbx"></span>
<ul class="dropdown-location-ul" id="dropdown-country" style="display:none;">
    <li class="dropdown-location-li">
        <strong>Deutschland</strong>
        <ul class="dropdown-location-ul" style="display:none;">
            <li class="dropdown-location-li">
                <strong>Brandenburg</strong>
                <ul class="dropdown-location-ul" style="display:none;">
                    <li class="dropdown-location-li">
                        <strong>Oranienburg</strong>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown-location-li">
                        <strong>Schwedt</strong>
                    </li>
                    ...
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-location-li">
                <strong>Berlin</strong>
            </li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-location-li">
        <strong>France</strong>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>

$('.dropdown-location-li').hover(function(){
    $(this).children('ul').css('left', $(this).parent('ul').width()+'px');
    $(this).children('ul').show();
}, function(){
    $(this).children('ul').hide();
});
```

This works just fine and now i need to make it on click to change value of near input to the name of location inside strong tag. I tried the code below but it appears that $(this) selecting the element and all his parents, but i need to get location from only the one i clicked. Please tell me how to do that correctly? Maybe i have completely wrong approach to do this and need to make all with id's and stuff, but i just wanted to minimise the amout of repeating js.

```
$('.dropdown-location-li').click(function(){
    $('#srch-area').val($(this).children('strong').text());
    $('#dropdown-country').hide();
});
```

This is how it shows in console. AS you can see when i click on Oranienburg it selects Brandenburg and Deutschland as well which are the parents of the element i clicked.
[console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWF10.jpg)

Comment: Is there a reason that you are not using `<select>` for a drop down list?  Because I assume you want to filter the Region drop down based on the Country selection, and again the City drop down based on the Region selection?

**Edit** I noticed that you are actually doing `$('.dropdown-location-li').click` but in your HTML you have a parent (The Region) having the exact same class.  So this means that it is actually clicking on the parent.  I would suggest changing your classes to .dropdown-region-li, .dropdown-country-li and .dropdown-city-li

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have nested `.dropdown-location-li` elements, so the click keeps propagating up to the other LI elements, firing the event handler again etc.
You should stop the propagation the first time

```
$('.dropdown-location-li').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();

    $('#srch-area').val($(this).children('strong').text());
    $('#dropdown-country').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, everything was so simple, im happy now =)

Answer (score 0):

try to use [JQuery Find](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

$(this).find('strong').text()

Comment: No, i tried this before and its doing just the same, the answer is to use stopPropagation();